# Does layoutSubviews available in ios4?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, uiscrollview

I am working in Xcode 3.2 and ios 4.1. I need to work on work on layoutSubviews, but i didn't find that function in both windows and view based application. 
Can anyone tell me whether the "layoutSubviews" available in ios4x or not. If available then tell me where.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Here's Apple docs link: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html

Answer (score 1):

From [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/layoutSubviews)

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
```

> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
>
> Subclasses can override this method as needed to perform more precise
>   layout of their subviews. You should override this method only if the
>   autoresizing behaviors of the subviews do not offer the behavior you
>   want. You can use your implementation to set the frame rectangles of
>   your subviews directly.
>   You should not call this method directly. If you want to force a
>   layout update, call the setNeedsLayout method instead to do so prior
>   to the next drawing update. If you want to update the layout of your
>   views immediately, call the layoutIfNeeded method.